Closure of a set with infinite product topology
In a certain exercise I have been asked to find whether the closure of the set $A, cl(A)$ with the topologies $\tau_{box},\tau_{product}$, defined below.

$\tau_{box}$, which consists on basic open sets of the form $\prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} U_i$, with $U_i$ open sets in $\mathbb{R}$.
$\tau_{product}$, which consists on basic open sets of the form $\prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} A_i$, with $A_i = \mathbb{R}$ with the exception of finite number of indices, which are open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ but not the whole space.

The set $A \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is defined as the one whose members are real sequences $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_i = 0$ $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}$, with the exception of a finite number of elements of the sequence.

I would define the set $A$ as infinite union of sets of the form $\prod_{j = 1}^{\infty} U_j$, where $U_j = \{0\}$ excepting for some sets that are $U_j = \mathbb{R}$ (a finite number of them). The difference between the sets whose union form $A$ is the order in which the $\mathbb{R}$ (a finite number) appear, as well as the amount of them.

I claim that $cl(A) = \prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} \mathbb{R}$ in both topologies, and I reached that conclusion supposing that if the closure was a set of the form $cl(A) = \prod_{j = 1}^{\infty}V_j$ with $V_j = \mathbb{R}$ excepting for one $V_k$ that can be any other set (or the union of sets of this type), then since the set $\prod_{j = 1}^{k-1} \{ 0 \} \times \mathbb{R} \times \prod_{j = k+1}^{\infty} \{0\}$ (which is an element of the union of sets that form $A$) is not included in $cl(A)$, but $cl(A)$ is the smallest closed set that contains $A$, so there is a contradiction (in the case that the closure had less "$\mathbb{R}$ factors" in the product, it would be the same).

Is my reasoning right? Is there a way to express this with a clearer and more specific notation?

No, the set $A$ is defined as the one which consists on infinite real sequences such that there are just a finite number of terms different of zero, but the remaining ones are all zero.

You are halfway correct.
In the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, it is indeed true that ${\rm Cl} A$ is the entire space. This is easily checked, because for any point $x = x_1 \times x_2 \times \dots$ in the space, any basis element $U = U_1 \times U_2 \times \dots$ containing $x$ must satisfy that there exists some $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $U_n = \mathbb{R}$ for all $n > N$; then the point $x_1 \times x_2 \times \dots \times x_N \times 0 \times 0 \times \dots$ is contained in $U \cap A$.
But in the box topology on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, $A$ is itself closed. To show this, let $y = y_1 \times y_2 \times \dots \in \mathbb{R}^\omega - A$. Consider the following basis element $V = V_1 \times V_2 \times \dots$ containing $y$: if $y_k = 0$, then let $V_k = \mathbb{R}$, otherwise, let $V_k = (y_k - \frac{1}{2} |y_k|, y_k + \frac{1}{2} |y_k|)$ (which does not contain $0$). This neighborhood clearly does not intersect $A$, because for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, there exists some $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ with $m > n$ such that $y_m \ne 0$, meaning $V_m$ does not contain $0$.
